# Performance on InsertManyAsync

Tags: entity-framework, bulkinsert, abp

I'm inserting 90,000 entities in certain batch sizes (tried 100,500, 1000 etc), but can't get speed.
That amount of entities takes me approximately 50 minutes.

I tried many batch sizes

```
int batchSize = 500;
i = 1;

var batches = nichoInvoices.Batch(batchSize);

foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    Logger.LogInformation($"Seeding Invoices {i * batchSize}");

    await _invManager.InvoiceRepository.InsertManyAsync(batch, true);
    i++;
}

Logger.LogInformation($"End Seeding Invoices");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use a non-transactional [Unit of Work](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.1/Unit-Of-Work):

```cs
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(requiresNew: true, isTransactional: false)) // +
{                                                                                     // +
    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation($"Seeding Invoices {i * batchSize}");

        await _invManager.InvoiceRepository.InsertManyAsync(batch, true);
        i++;
    }

    await uow.CompleteAsync();                                                        // +
}                                                                                     // +
```

Or use a separate Unit of Work for each batch:

```cs
foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    Logger.LogInformation($"Seeding Invoices {i * batchSize}");

    using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(requiresNew: true))         // +
    {                                                                     // +
        await _invManager.InvoiceRepository.InsertManyAsync(batch, true);
        await uow.CompleteAsync();                                        // +
    }                                                                     // +

    i++;
}
```